# Where clause with inner join not working for orders table

Tags: mysql, inner-join, where-clause

I have the following tables(with their columns in brackets):

- products(productID, productName, categoryID)
- categories(categoryID, categoryName)
- customers(customerID, customerName)
- orders(customerID, create_at, productID)

I can successfully use inner join to display all the order details and include the product and customer names.

```
select products.productName, orders.create_at, customers.customerName 
from orders 
inner join products on orders.productID=products.productID 
inner join customers on orders.customerID=customers.customerID;
```

Now I want to display only the orders in which the product belongs to category "laptop". And my attempt was the following:

```
select products.productName, orders.create_at, customers.customerName 
from orders 
inner join products on orders.productID=products.productID 
inner join customers on orders.customerID=customers.customerID where categories.categoryName='laptop';
```

But this doesn't work and I assume it is because the where clause should be based on a column that belongs to the orders table.

The error I get is the following:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'categories.categoryName' in 'where clause'
```

How can I show only orders which products belong to a specific category?

Comment: Did you forget to join to the categories table?

Comment: I didn't join categories because the categoryID is not included in the orders table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must join to the table `categories`:

```
select products.productName, orders.create_at, customers.customerName 
from orders 
inner join products on orders.productID=products.productID 
inner join categories on categories.categoryID=products.categoryID
inner join customers on orders.customerID=customers.customerID 
where categories.categoryName='laptop';
```

There must be a column like `categoryID` in both `products` and `categories`.
Sometimes a product may belong to more than 1 categories. In this case there must be another table that links products to categories.

Comment: Oops. This actually works! My understanding was that in the inner join each condition but be based on the from table, which in my case is the orders.
Appreciate the support.